# How can I achieve a functionality similar to "auto-insertion of timestamps"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a couple of fields `created_by` and `updated_by` in most of my tables. This would contain the user id of the user who created or updated the Object. is it possible to have a similar function like how rails handles `created_at`? I basically want it to function the same way as the timestamps insertion. I should be able to define in the columns in the migration script and configure rails to fetch the user object from a helper method everytime when it changes the particular object. Is there a direct way to do it or is there a plugin which does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also you can do this without gems but with [Rails Observers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html)

You can create observer like this:

```
class UserTouchObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :product, :post, :comment

  def after_create(model)
    update_attribute(:created_by, current_user.id) if model.respond_to?(:created_by)
  end

  def after_update(model)
    update_attribute(:updated_by, current_user.id) if model.respond_to?(:updated_by)
  end
end
```

Comment: this looks like a really nice solution but how do you get a reference to the controllers current_user from the observer? - `undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<UserTouchObserver:0x007ffe20f6ff38>`

Comment: I just put a gem together to handle this - might be useful to someone? https://github.com/house9/clerk uses the https://github.com/bokmann/sentient_user gem which keeps the current_user in Thread.current

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a few plugins on github that do just this:

- https://github.com/jnunemaker/user_stamp
- https://github.com/bokmann/userstamp_basic