# how to create our own base class and inherits all model from base class instead of ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i am working on a project, in that project for every model we have two properties common

1. Created_ts
2. Created_by

I want to add a base class in which i want to set these properties, i tried using

```
class BaseModel < ActiveRecords::Base

end

class Person < BaseModel

end
```

when i create an instance of Person model it gives exception, i am not sure why it is giving exception, may be because it is looking for table BaseModels.

can any one please suggest, how to do this.

Exception :

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "base_models" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"base_models"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"base_models"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "base_models" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"base_models"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"base_models"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Comment: can you give more details about the exception thrown please.

Comment: you can encapsulate the common functionality inside a Module and let ActiceRecord::Base include that module which then becomes available for all of your models

Comment: @Lynch i have added the exception details

Comment: @AmolPujari can you please give me some example Url may be, it might help me understand it better

Comment: @AmolPujari is it a good idea to edit ActiveRecord::Base class

Comment: @RicardoDelaFuente Thanks for the help but i am not looking for single table inheritance, i wanted to use a base class in which i can place common functionalities

Comment: @rajansoft1 yes it is a good idea to open ActiveRecord::Base while ensuring you do not override any known/hidden features or at least most commonly used

Comment: check out this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490681/how-can-i-achieve-a-functionality-similar-to-auto-insertion-of-timestamps

Answer (score 0):

we just need to make the base class as abstract class

for more reference seek below link

[Rails extending ActiveRecord::Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase)